# Composite Foreign Key Issue while using Inheritance in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have a JPA Entity StatsEntity which has a composite primary key that is also as foreign key to another Entity Roster. This is setup as a **@OneToOne** relationship using **@JoinColumns({@JoinColumn...})** annotations.

StatsEntity extends another entity CoreStatsEntity which is setup as @MappedSuperClass where as RosterEntity extends another entity CoreRoster using SINGLE_TABLE inheritance strategy.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Stats")
@IdClass(value = StatsEntity.Key.class)
public class StatsEntity extends CoreStatsEntity implements
    Stats {

@Id
private Integer competitionId;

@Id
private Integer playerId;

@Id
private Integer teamId;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "competitionId", referencedColumnName = "competitionId", insertable = false, updatable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "playerId", referencedColumnName = "personId", insertable = false, updatable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "teamId", referencedColumnName = "teamId", insertable = false, updatable=false) })
private RosterEntity roster;


....

}
```

**StatsEntity.Key**

```
 @Embeddable
public static class Key implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7349082038890396790L;

    @Column(name = "competitionId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer competitionId;

    @Column(name = "playerId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer playerId;

    @Column(name = "teamId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer teamId;

    public Key() {
        super();
    }

    public Key(int competitionId, int playerId, int teamId) {
        this.competitionId = Integer.valueOf(competitionId);
        this.playerId = Integer.valueOf(playerId);
        this.teamId = Integer.valueOf(teamId);
    }

    public int getTeamId() {
        return teamId.intValue();
    }

    public void setTeamId(int teamId) {
        this.teamId = Integer.valueOf(teamId);
    }

    public int getPlayerId() {
        return playerId.intValue();
    }

    public void setPlayerId(int playerId) {
        this.playerId = Integer.valueOf(playerId);
    }

    public int getCompetitionId() {
        return competitionId.intValue();
    }

    public void setCompetitionId(int CompetitionId) {
        this.competitionId = Integer.valueOf(CompetitionId);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (object == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(object instanceof Key)) {
            return false;
        }

        Key other = (Key) object;
        return Utils.equals(other.getTeamId(), this.getTeamId())
                && Utils.equals(other.getPlayerId(), this.getPlayerId())
                && Utils.equals(other.getCompetitionId(),
                        this.getCompetitionId());
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Utils.hashCode(this.teamId, this.playerId,
                this.competitionId);

    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Utils.toString("CompetitionPlayerStatsEntity.Key",
                this.teamId, this.playerId, this.competitionId);
    }
}
```

**CoreStatsEntity.java**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class CoreStatsEntity
{}
```

**RosterEntity**

```
 @Entity
 @DiscriminatorValue("20")
  public class RosterEntity extends
    CoreRosterEntity  {

    //.... attributes, getters, setters

    }
```

**CoreRosterEntity.java**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("0")
@Table(name="Roster")
@IdClass(CoreRoster.Key.class)           

@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="discriminator", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public class CoreRosterEntity  {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1521639115446682871L;

@Id
private Integer competitionId;

@Id
private Integer teamId;

@Id
private Integer playerId;

//.. getters, setters and other attributes
```

}

**CoreRoster.Key.class inside CoreRoster.java**

```
@Embeddable
public static class Key implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

    @Column(name="competitionId", nullable=false)
    private Integer competitionId;

    @Column(name="teamId", nullable=false)
    private Integer teamId;

    @Column(name="personId", nullable=false)
    private Integer playerId;

    public Key() {
        super();
    }

    public Key(int competitionId, int teamId, int playerId) {
        this.competitionId = Integer.valueOf(competitionId);
        this.teamId = Integer.valueOf(teamId);
        this.playerId = Integer.valueOf(playerId);
    }

    public int getPlayerId() {
        return playerId.intValue();
    }

    public void setPlayerId(int playerId) {
        this.playerId = Integer.valueOf(playerId);
    }

    public int getTeamId() {
        return teamId.intValue();
    }

    public void setTeamId(int teamId) {
        this.teamId = Integer.valueOf(teamId);
    }

    public int getCompetitionId() {
        return this.competitionId.intValue();
    }

    public void setCompetitionId(int competitionId) {
        this.competitionId = Integer.valueOf(competitionId);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (object == this) { return true; }
        if (!(object instanceof Key)) { return false; }

        Key other = (Key) object;
        return Utils.equals(other.getCompetitionId(), this.getCompetitionId()) &&
               Utils.equals(other.getTeamId(), this.getTeamId()) &&
               Utils.equals(other.getPlayerId(), this.getPlayerId());
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Utils.hashCode(this.competitionId, this.teamId,
                              this.playerId);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Utils.toString("CoreRoster.Key",
                              this.competitionId, this.teamId,
                              this.playerId);
    }
}
```

When I persist StatsEntity, it gets persisted. But when I try to find it using the primary key it gives me an error:

```
    StatsEntity playerStats = new StatsEntity();
    //set all values
this.persist(playerStats);              
entityManager.find(StatsEntity.class, playerStats.getId()); //getId returns the composite primary key

 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for class   com.sports.RosterEntity. Expected: class com.sports.CoreRoster$Key, got class com.espn.sports.StatsEntity$Key
```

My first question here is, is the @OneToOne mapping I have given correct or not?
If it is correct then why this error appears when I try to find the entity using primarykey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't posted full source code, especially of your primary key class, but you've mapped foreign key as read-only, which is required when single column is mapped more than once.

I see however that you id columns are exactly the same 3 columns that are foreign key to RosterEntity, rights? In that case this RosterEntity should be your **ID**, which would simplify your design.

What is the return type of your getId() method? The problem is propably with definition or usage of **IdClass**.

Comment: have edited the question. getId's return type is Object, but I return a object of StatsEntity.Key. Let me try your suggestions

Comment: Roster.Key cant be made the ID as the columns in it are different name.(personId instead of playerId)

Comment: Added a minor change to the DB columns (thanks to DBA) and now I have made the key as RosterEntity. Worked. Thanks